# Do I really need to have SharePoint Server installed on my computer?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sharepoint-2010, webpart, sharepoint

Ok,

So I have another question about the servers. I’m reading this book here about created Visual Web Parts for SharePoint using Visual Studio 2010/ASP.NET, however when I select New Project-> Visual Web Part | I am giving the following error message:

"A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer. A SharePoint server must be installed to work with SharePoint projects."

I even went to the farm administration level to see if I could create my web part there using Visu

We have SharePoint Servers and I am the Administrator and Designer, but again, I am still new to SharePoint. How would I know if my computer is connected to the SharePoint Server? Does it REALLY need to be connected to this server or is there a work around? I created a project in Visual Studio a few months ago that we are wanting to use as a web part, however I believe this is the first step I need to take to get this done. The program was created in SQL Server 2010 and the data resides on SQL Server 2005 and the SharePoint Server is SQL 2008...is this going to be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its a connection to Sharepoint that's required, its the DLLs that are installed along with Sharepoint that your project needs access to.

In my experience, Sharepoint development always starts with setting up a development SP instance, usually in a VM along with Visual Studio for this reason.

As MSDN says,

> When you create or customize
>   SharePoint solutions, it is usually
>   best to develop the solution on a
>   local computer where Microsoft
>   SharePoint Server 2010 or Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation 2010 is
>   installed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Comment: @Nexus- Thank you Nexus. Well, for the mean time I guess I am going to create my webpart view the Page Viewer until I can get the server installed on my computer and then I have to re-code my entire program to add containers and the like before it can be embedded in SharePoint.